# Spring Repository Rollback Issue

Tags: java, spring, repository, rollback

I want to write a method to do two deleting operations.

```
 @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void deleteFromDB(Collection<ImageQuery> completed, Collection<ImageQueryItem> deletedItems) {
    imageQueryItemRepository.delete(deletedItems);
    imageQueryRepository.delete(completed);
}
```

This my code and I want if second method throws exception, deleteFromDB methods was rollback. But it doesn't work. I throw uncheck exception but first method doesn't rollback.

Answer (score 0):

Pleas check the sub methods, the don't opena new transaction, such as REQUIRESNEW.

Comment: These repositories are spring repository. They use SingleJpaRepository. Don't use RequiresNew.